# Axon Command is delivered to EventHandler

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I'm trying to send a  `Command` to an `Aggregate`. When I send a `Command` to an `Aggregate`, Aggregate's `EventHandler` method is invoked before the `CommandHanlder` method.
I don't know how this is possible as I just want to invoke the `CommandHandler` method.

First I send `IssueCardCommand` to create GiftCard `Aggregate` and send `ReimburseCardCommand` to invoke AggregateMember's `CommandHandler` method.

```
@Autowired
CommandGateway cm;
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {

        String cardId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        int transactionValue = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

        cm.sendAndWait(new IssueCardCommand(cardId, transactionValue));
        
        cm.sendAndWait(new ReimburseCardCommand(cardId, transactionValue));

    };
}
```

this is `GiftCardTransaction`(Aggregates' child entity) `CommandHandler` method which I wanna invoke

```
@CommandHandler
public void handle(ReimburseCardCommand cmd) {
    log.info("GiftCardTransaction Handler " + transactionId);
    log.info(reimbursed);

    // if (reimbursed) {
    // throw new IllegalStateException("Transaction already reimbursed");
    // }
    apply(new CardReimbursedEvent(cmd.getTransactionId(), transactionId, transactionValue));
}
```

and this is `Aggregate`

```
@Log4j2
@Aggregate
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GiftCard {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;

    @AggregateMember(routingKey = "transactionId", eventForwardingMode = ForwardMatchingInstances.class)
    private List<GiftCardTransaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    private int remainingValue;


    @CommandHandler
    public GiftCard(IssueCardCommand cmd) {
        log.info("GiftCard is created");
        apply(new CardIssuedEvent(cmd.getCardId(), cmd.getAmount()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler // 4.
    public void on(CardIssuedEvent evt) {
        id = evt.getCardId();
        remainingValue=evt.getAmount();
        log.info(id);
        transactions.add(new GiftCardTransaction(id,remainingValue));
        String cardId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        apply(new CardReimbursedEvent(cardId,id,evt.getAmount()));
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(ReimburseCardCommand cmd) {
        String cardId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        apply(new CardReimbursedEvent(cardId,id,cmd.getTransactionValue()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

> Aggregate's EventHandler method is invoked before the CommandHanlder method

what do you mean by that?
I am suspecting you are experiencing the Event Sourcing part of the Aggregate.

Basically, your flow should be this one:

1. `IssueCardCommand` -> handlded by the `Aggregate`, effectively creating one for you and applying the subsequent `CardIssuedEvent` which will be immediately handlded by your `EventSourcingHandler`.
2. `ReimburseCardCommand` -> your `Aggregate` is reconstructed from the past (Event Sourcing), meaning the all the `@EventSourcingHandler`s will be called prior to the Command Handler. When the `Aggregate` is up to date with the Events, it will handle your command based on the `@CommandHandler` methods.

obs: Seems like you have a Duplicated Command Handler method, one on the `@Aggregate` and another on the `@AggregateMember`. I would double check if that's correct and if you are getting your Command on both places which I believe you aren't.

Comment: thanks for ur answering 
but why @EventSourcingHandlers will be called prior to the Command Handler?

Comment: This is what Event Sourcing does. In a nut shell, your Aggregate will 'always' be reconstructed based on past events before it can decide to accept or not (validations) the new command. So, all `@EventSourcingHandler`s will be called, the state of your Aggregate reconstructed and the new Command can be applied (or not). You can read more about it [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/architecture-overview/event-sourcing)